# Convert Py to EXE and still use variables?

Tags: python, excel, pyinstaller, xlwings

So right now I have a Python script which automates the downloading of several CSV reports from a portal, which are then picked up by an Excel macro to be combined and formatted.

The Python script itself is called from the same Excel macro, and is passed some variables needed for the reports to be generated (*date ranges*, *report url*, *report category* etc.); for this I am using `xlwings` and `webbrowser`.

The problem is that I need to pass this task to a non-technical user to run, who for security reasons cannot have Python installed on their PC so I was thinking to convert the Py file to an EXE. I know I can do this using `PyInstaller` but I'm not sure how to (or if it's even possible to) still be able to pass variables to the script when it runs as an EXE.

Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Comment: could you pass the variables via a file? A .json for example would work.

Comment: You can still pass arguments via. the command line as you would for any other program. However for a non-technical user, who may not be comfortable using a console and typing stuff in you could use a simple configuration file or a basic GUI.